# SQL LIKE is only working With Full Name

Tags: sql, sql-like

In one of my sp I have following lines of code

```
select distinct (a.itemid), a.itemcode, v.itemdescription

from aitem a
    INNER JOIN vwitemdescription v ON a.itemID = v.itemID 

WHERE a.active=1
-----------------------------------------
AND (@ItemDesc like '%'+ a.itemdescription +'%')
-----------------------------------------
```

If I give @ItemDesc value in full description, I get values and if I give @ItemDesc value in half description I get nothing in return.

*For Example :*

If I giv

```
@ItemDesc = 'Cow Dung - '
```

I get result as

```
---------------------------------------
|itemid | itemcode | itemdescription  |
--------------------------------------
|   63  | 40-17005 |   Cow Dung -     |
---------------------------------------
```

And even if I cut the string as `@ItemDesc = 'Cow Dung'` I get the same results,

But if I cut it into `@ItemDesc = 'Cow'` or only to single character I don't get any results.

I want to load the item even if I enter only a single charecter in it.

Is there anything wrong with my code? How to get it right?

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product (and your question contains non-standard SQL). Please add a tag for the database product you are using

Comment: `DISTINCT` is a part of `SELECT DISTINCT`, and works on the whole selected rows. Skip those redundant parentheses to make the query clearer, i.e. simply do `select distinct a.itemid, a.itemcode, ...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to switch the items in your `LIKE` expression:

```
AND a.itemdescription LIKE '%' + @ItemDesc + '%'
```

Using this logic, any *substring* of the `itemdescription` would match.  For example the following is a true condition:

```
AND `Cow Dung - ` LIKE '%Cow%'
```

Here is the full query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.itemid, a.itemcode, v.itemdescription
FROM aitem a
INNER JOIN vwitemdescription v
    ON a.itemID = v.itemID 
WHERE
    a.active = 1 AND
    a.itemdescription LIKE '%' + @ItemDesc + '%';
```

Answer (score 1):

Comparison variable should be always at the right side of the statement. Your new query should be as below.

```
select distinct (a.itemid), a.itemcode, v.itemdescription    
from aitem a
    INNER JOIN vwitemdescription v ON a.itemID = v.itemID     
WHERE a.active=1    
--changed condition start    
AND (a.itemdescription like '%'+ @ItemDesc +'%')
--changed condition end
```

Comment: "always" is a bit too strong, there may be situations where the stated order is correct. But you are right, given the examples the order should be switched.

Comment: Thanks Hans you are right, i have posted on the basis of the current case.